# Por que não está entrando neste if/else?

Tags: java, if, else

Eu executo esse código e o `if`/`else if` não estão entrando. O que pode ser?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class VerificaLetra {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        String sexo = " ";
        String letra;
        Scanner scan;
    
        System.out.print("Informe o sexo. F para feminino e M "+
                     "para Masculino: ");
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        letra = scan.nextLine();
    
        if (letra == "f" || letra == "F") {
            sexo = "Sexo = Feminino";
        }
        else if (letra == "m" || letra == "M") {
            sexo = "Sexo = Masculino";
        }
        System.out.println(sexo);        
    }
}
```

Comment: É porque strings são objetos, você precisa usar `letra.equals("m")`. Tem várias perguntas aqui sobre isso, marquei a sua como duplicata de uma delas.

Comment: Obrigado! Sou novo no site, mas vou tentar pesquisar antes na próxima.
Vou testar sua resposta, o tópico que você mandou também tem umas respostas legais!

Comment: Deu certo. Eu li o tópico e consegui entender bem o conceito. Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em Java `String` é uma classe normal e como a linguagem não possui sobrecarga de operador, só pode fazer a comparação com o método [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class VerificaLetra {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Informe o sexo. F para feminino e M para Masculino: ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String letra = scan.nextLine();
        String sexo = " ";
        if (letra.equals("f") || letra.equals("F")) sexo = "Sexo = Feminino";
        else if (letra.equals("m") || letra.equals("M")) sexo = "Sexo = Masculino";
        System.out.println(sexo);        
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/glogV8). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/bahirjzp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/Equals.java).

Você poderia usar o [`equalsIgnoreCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) e fazer só uma comparação em cada `if`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Não conhecia esse equalsIgnoreCase() vai me ser bem util!